# notify_one only when there are waiting threads is correct?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've seen the following type of a dispatch queue implementation several times where the thread pushing a new element to the queue calls notify_one **only when the queue was empty before pushing the element**. This condition would reduce unnecessary notify_one calls because q.size() != 0 before pushing a new element means there are only active threads (assuming there are multiple consumer threads).

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

using Item = int;
std::queue<Item> q;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;

void process(Item i){}

void pop() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    // This thread releases the lock and start waiting.
    // When notified, the thread start trying to re-acquire the lock and exit wait().
    // During the attempt (and thus before `pop()`), can another `push()` call acquire the lock? 
    cv.wait(lock, [&]{return !q.empty();});
    auto item = q.front();
    q.pop();
    process(item);
  }
}

void push(Item i) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
  q.push(i);
  if (q.size() == 1) cv.notify_one();
}

int main() { /* ... */ }
```

However, is the following scenario possible ? Suppose that all the consumer threads are waiting.

1. the pushing thread acquires the lock and push a new element and calls notify_one because the queue was empty.
2. a notified thread tries to re-acquire the lock (and exit wait())
3. the pushing thread acquires the lock again and pushes another element **before a notified thread re-acquires the lock**.

In this case, no notify_one call wouldn't occur after 3. and there would be only one active thread when the queue isn't empty.

Comment: I don't get your concern about #3. Please provide your consumer thread implementation. Generally consumer thread should acquire the lock, pop one element and processing. Then release the lock. After that, #1 would happen.

Comment: Meanwhile all other consumer threads should wait until `q` is not empty.

Comment: Are you worried about [_spurious wakeups_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)?

Comment: Is there any re-acquiring attempt in the `condition_variable::wait()` when the thread is notified ? My concern (and #2, #3) is about this behavior.

Comment: @wanwan You don't show a [mre] so .. we can only talk about about your code. If you instead show a [mre], it'll be more real.

Comment: Your worry is related to consumer thread which isn't shown in your post. Please [edit] to provide a [mre].

Comment: I like the edit of the question - but, it's still not a [mre]. If you try to compile what you've shown: [this is what you get](https://godbolt.org/z/vjPMrToeP)

Comment: Check the spec of [cv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). It acquires mutex when it wakes up. So operation should be atomic.

Comment: @LouisGo Are you thinking about _spurious wakeups_ or missing that point?

Comment: @TedLyngmo isn't the predicate `!q.empty()` not enough for spurious wakeup?

Comment: @LouisGo It can be, if synchronized with a condition variable for example.

Comment: For example, when "It acquires mutex when it wakes up", fails to acquire for some reason and retries , is there any chance that another thread will acquire the lock during the retrying. (And sorry for the lack of information...)

Comment: Or when the notified thread is immediately context-switched before it acquires the lock.

Comment: @wanwan My position on this is biased. Spurious wakeups are a pain and people have to code around them all the time. It's left like that in the name of "possible optimizations" as I've understood it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo according to the [wake on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait). The second one should be suffice since `This overload may be used to ignore spurious awakenings while waiting for a specific condition to become true.`

Comment: IMHO, we should believe that the standard has handled it unless we found the flaw.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, you can use patterns to work around this. The primary pattern is even stated as an example - just so that people know how to use it. It's silly in my book

Comment: Thank for your comments, but I think my question is not about spurious wakeups.

Comment: @LouisGo "So operation should be atomic." Do you mean that wakeup + acquire is atomic and the notified thread is guaranteed to be the first thread that acquires the lock after the last release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the operation after wake up

According to [wake's doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

> 1. **Atomically unlocks lock**, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on *this. The thread will be unblocked when notify_all() or notify_one() is executed. It may also be unblocked spuriously. When unblocked, regardless of the reason, **lock is reacquired** and wait exits.

Means your code is atomic between `#1` to `#2` when it's woken up. Don't need to worry about the synchronization since your compiler should handle it.

```cpp
void pop() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    // When sleep, cv release the lock
    cv.wait(lock, [&]{return !q.empty();});   // <----#1
    // When wake up, it acquires the lock
    auto item = q.front();
    q.pop();
    process(item);                            // <----#2
  }
}
```

### For spurious wakeup

The second overload with predicate would handle spurious wakeup for you.
`template< class Predicate > void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate stop_waiting ); (2) (since C++11)`

> 2. Equivalent to

```
while (!stop_waiting()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

> This overload may be used to ignore spurious awakenings while waiting for a specific condition to become true.

> Note that lock must be acquired before entering this method, and it is reacquired after wait(lock) exits, which means that lock can be used to guard access to stop_waiting().

That is the `condition_variable` overload with predicate would save you from spurious wake up.
The handmade while loop for checking spurious wake up is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answering! I think this answers my question. So,  the "When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is reacquired and wait exits." part, unblock + reacquire, is also done atomically, right?

Comment: Yes, both unblock and block should be atomic for releasing/acquiring the lock though it doesn't explicitly state that acquiring lock and unblocking thread is atomic .